# Upload file and create sharing link in Nextcloud using Python script

Tags: python, api, aiohttp, webdav, nextcloud

I like to upload a file to a specific place in Nextcloud and get a public sharing link (just the defaults, no password etc.) from it on the command line, using Python, ideally async, but whatever works. I'm sure, that people already did this and I can benefit from their work :-) Thank you in advance!